# Смена мест элементов массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Идея программы - замена порядка номеров в массиве на обратный. Но в итоге выдает `[undefined, 1, 3, 4, 5]`.

```js
function reverseArray (array) {
  let tempVar = [];
  for (i=0; i<Math.floor(array.length/2); i++) {
  tempVar = array[i];
  array[i] = array[array.lenght-1-i];
  array[array.lenght-1-i] = tempVar;
  };
return array
};
console.log(reverseArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Опечатка в названии свойства `lenght`

```js
function reverseArray (array) {
  let tempVar;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
    tempVar = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - 1 - i];
    array[array.length - 1 - i] = tempVar;
  };
  return array;
};
console.log(reverseArray([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]));
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Так же обратите внимание на метод [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Пример: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].reverse() // [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`